# Remove bundler flags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I remove the flags that I applied to bundler? This is what happens when I run bundle install:

```
bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
```

I'm looking for an answer that will help me run:

```
bundle install
```

Without all of the other flags. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `bundle` with flags, a file is created at `.bundle/config` containing YAML data with the key/value pairs of your flags.

From your project root directory (which contains the `.bundle/` directory, run the following to clear the folder and the `config` file contained within.

```
rm -r .bundle
```

You can learn more about the config file **[in the docs](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html)**.